# Python XGB Labels not reading the correct label size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xgboost

I'm getting an error when trying to run a simple XGB.  The error is mentioned in the below but the solution is not helping.

[XGBoost Error info.labels.size() != 0U (0 vs. 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187225/xgboost-error-info-labels-size-0u-0-vs-0)

The error is as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-748-7f7917b57181> in <module>
     11 param = {'max_depth':3, 'eta':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic'}
     12 
---> 13 bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)
     14 preds = bst.predict(dtest)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, xgb_model, callbacks)
    207                            evals=evals,
    208                            obj=obj, feval=feval,
--> 209                            xgb_model=xgb_model, callbacks=callbacks)
    210 
    211 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks)
     72         # Skip the first update if it is a recovery step.
     73         if version % 2 == 0:
---> 74             bst.update(dtrain, i, obj)
     75             bst.save_rabit_checkpoint()
     76             version += 1

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in update(self, dtrain, iteration, fobj)
   1247             _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(self.handle,
   1248                                                     ctypes.c_int(iteration),
-> 1249                                                     dtrain.handle))
   1250         else:
   1251             pred = self.predict(dtrain, training=True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\torch_env\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _check_call(ret)
    187     """
    188     if ret != 0:
--> 189         raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
    190 
    191 

XGBoostError: [15:11:21] C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.0.0/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:60: Check failed: preds.Size() == info.labels_.Size() (3843 vs. 0) : labels are not correctly providedpreds.size=3843, label.size=0
```

So the above points to a label size issue.  When I run the following code, my training data (`train_xgb`) and my label data (`test_xgb`) match.

```
train_xgb = train_dummies.iloc[:, 2:]
test_xgb = train_dummies.iloc[:, 2]
print(train_xgb.shape, test_xgb.shape, type(train_xgb), type(test_xgb))

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_xgb)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(test_xgb)
```

Here is the result of the print statement above:
`(3843, 3143) (3843,) <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

I've tried changing the labels to their own `dataframe` and `numpy` array with no change in the error.

Comment: Will you give LightGBM a chance?

Comment: I’ll give anything a chance that gives good results! I’d still like to k ow why the above is not working but I’ll look into liggtgbm.